# Test a method with a dependency on a base property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, unit-testing, moq

I have a QuickController class that inherits from a BaseController. A method in QuickController calls a property on the BaseController which have a dependency on ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.

I want to unit test QuickController but can't find a way to get rid of that dependency. Here's my test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var moqServiceWrapper = new Mock<IServiceWrapper>();

    var controller = new QuickController(moqServiceWrapper.Object);

    //Act
    var result = controller.Estimator(QuickEstimatorViewModel);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ViewResult));
}
```

The QuickController class

```
public class QuickController : BaseController
{
    public QuickController(IServiceWrapper service)
        : base(service) { }

    public ActionResult Estimator(QuickEstimatorViewModel viewModel)
    {
        viewModel.RiskAddressLocation = RiskAddressLocation;

        ....

        return View("QuickQuote", viewModel);
    }
}
```

And the BaseController property

```
public RiskAddressLocation RiskAddressLocation
{
    get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["..."]
                            .ToEnum<RiskAddressLocation>(true); }
}
```

I also tried to call the method on a FakeQuickController that inherit from QuickController, but can't override the property, it's the one in the BaseController that is always called.

Is there anything I can do here?

**Update**

From the accepted answer here's what I had that VS2013 didn't like

```
public class BaseController{
    public virtual RiskAddressLocation RiskAddressLocation {get{...;}
}

public class QuickController : BaseController{}

public class FakeQuickController : QuickController{
    public override RiskAddressLocation RiskAddressLocation
    { 
        get { return ...} // Doesn't compile (cannot override because
                 //BaseController.RiskAddressLocation' is not a function
    }
}
```

This however, works fine

```
public class BaseController{
    public virtual RiskAddressLocation RiskAddressLocation(){...}
}

public class QuickController : BaseController{}

public class FakeQuickController : QuickController{
    public override RiskAddressLocation RiskAddressLocation()
    { 
        return ... ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you want to [mock ConfigurationManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486087/how-to-mock-configurationmanager-appsettings-with-moq) rather than attempt to mock the base?

Comment: Fair enough @RGraham, but how do I intercept the RiskAddressLocation in the base class to be able to mock it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a non-virtual property that depends on a concrete method that you want to mock.

Basically you have three options (given no context, I'd suggest either of the latter two):

- Use an isolation framework, like e.g. [Microsoft Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- modify your `BaseController` and change the property to virtual
- remove the dependency in code (which you should do in the first place if you want to follow SOLID design), e.g. wrapping it in a separate interface

Comment: If I make RiskAddressLocation virtual I can only override it from QuickController. I can't override it, say from a FakeQuickController that inherits from QuickController.

Comment: That's incorrect - if you make a member virtual, you can override it in any derived class, no matter how many times separated. To give you the simplest possible example - you can override `ToString` on any class (even one that inherits from a different class), even though the original method is defined on `System.Object`.

Comment: You are right... and wrong ;) You see, RiskAddressLocation is a property and that doesn't allow me to override base from the grand-child. Finally I got some meaningful error and it said it's not possible because is not a function. So I changed from a property to a function and... it works :) Accepting your answer anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @kooshka I'm glad it works for you, but out of curiosity - could you share how you tried to do it? Because you **definitely can** override a property from a 'grand-child'; this code simply works: http://pastebin.com/fqc5Sf5Z

Answer (score 3):

You could write an adapter for Configuration to allow you to provide stub configuration in unit tests. I'm sure there are many different implementations for this; I like [Nathan Gloyn's `IConfigurationManager` implementation](https://github.com/NathanGloyn/IConfigurationManager).

Then you would register `WebConfigurationManagerAdapter` as the component to use for the `IConfigurationManager` service to use in production and use Moq to mock the interface in your unit tests.

One other thing to note, if your ViewModel is a simple DTO, I would pass a real instance in the unit test as there is no advantage to mocking it.