# How to mock ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings with moq in Unit Test case project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-functions, moq

I am writing a unit test cases fro Azure function.In my function app configuration section i have added my connection string.

When the azure function runs in azure below line of code is working fine.

```
var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

If i am calling the azure function from unit test case this line is throwing exception.
"object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Form unit test case how i can execute this line of code.(using Moq).

Test Method :

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetDataFromAzureSQL_Test()
    {


         var req = new HttpRequestMessage();

        var obj = new Modeltest
        {
            id = 1,
            name ="",
            location=""

        };

        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        req.Content = content;
        var result = await Function.Function1.Run(req, new Mock<ILogger>().Object);
        Assert.IsTrue("OK" == result.StatusCode.ToString());

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock ConfigurationManager.AppSettings with moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486087/how-to-mock-configurationmanager-appsettings-with-moq)

Comment: No,Test project we have to call the Azure function and above mentioned line of code should cover in the code coverage.

Comment: @Elina could you please post the code of your unit test and the corresponding azure unction ? Thanks

Comment: in .net core I always create a base class and put something like this:

    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .AddJsonFile($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}appsettings.json");
            _configuration = builder.Build();
then 
  var connectionString =  _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")

Comment: I think you've MISSED the Appconfig.xml in your test project (you're in a full framework app cause ConfigurationManager doesn't exist in .net core)

Comment: Appconfig.xml is present in the test project

Comment: Usually in Azure Functions (and .Net Core in general) you inject an `IConfiguration` instead, and use that to get your connection strings (and of course it's easily mockable).

Comment: can you please give me some sample code

Comment: Add AppSetting file in your test project and put dummy value